# event.preventDefault() para anexo com php e js

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho o seguinte script abaixo que faz uma validação no formulário de contato e mostra a mensagem em div como a mensagem foi enviada ou não, da forma que esta abaixo esta enviado a mensagem normal em meu email, porem nesse mesmo formulário tenho um campo de anexo e quando tento enviar um anexo não recebo nada em meu email.

```
// Contact form 
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $("#main-contact-form").serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Enviando Mensagem...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Mensagem enviada. O mais breve possível retornaremos o contato.</p>').delay(9000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

> Formulário

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="contact-form" action="envia.php" method="post" id="main-contact-form"> <!--  chama o envia.php --> 
                                <!--<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" form action="envia.php"> -->   

                             <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text"  input name="nomeremetente" id="nomeremetente" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required>
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="telefone" input name="telefone" class="form-control" placeholder="DDD + Telefone" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="empresa" input name="empresa" class="form-control" placeholder="Empresa" required>
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="cidade" input name="cidade" class="form-control" placeholder="Cidade" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" input name="emailremetente" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                               <!--<input type="text" input name="assunto" class="form-control" placeholder="Assunto" required>-->
                               <select id="mySelect" input name="assunto" size="1" class="form-control"  required>
                               <option value="Sem Assunto">Selecione o Assunto</option>
                               <option value="Comercial">Comercial</option>
                               <option value="Cotação">Cotação</option>
                               <option value="Informação">Informação</option>
                               <option value="Reclamação">Reclamação</option>
                               <option value="Sugestão">Sugestão</option>
                               <option value="Trabalhe Conosco">Trabalhe Conosco</option>
                               <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
                               </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group" id="inputOculto">
                                  <input id="anexo" name="arquivo" type="file"  class="form-control-anexo"  input/> 
                            </div>            

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <textarea input name="mensagem" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Mensagem" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Mensagem</button>
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro verifique na declaração do formulário se possui a tag `enctype="multipart/form-data"` depois tente Utilizando a classe [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

**Ex**

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Enviando Mensagem...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Mensagem enviada. O mais breve possível retornaremos o contato.</p>').delay(9000).fadeOut();
    });
```

Comment: Sim, ja tem essa tag, tanto que se tento enviar o anexo sem passar pelo js ele enviar normal.

Comment: Com o formData funcionou?

Comment: Vou da uma pesquisada nesse formData, não tenho conhecimento nessa função, tem algum exemplo que possa me ajudar?

Comment: Opa agora que vi que você mandou um script, irei tentar e ja retorno.

Comment: Também não deu certo da forma que você passou.

Comment: Usou assim :
new FormData($("#main-contact-form")),
ou
new FormData($("#main-contact-form"),? é que acabei esquecendo de um parêntese ali.

Comment: Usei assim data: new FormData($("#main-contact-form")) e tambem assim  data = new FormData($('#main-contact-form").get(0));..em ambos nem chegou a chamar o envio.

Comment: Consegue ver alguma mensagem de erro no console?

Comment: Tente new FormData($("#main-contact-form")[0])

Comment: Tentei dessa forma que voce passou e tambem nao deu, no console aparece isso: TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

Comment: Realizei alteração na resposta acrescentando isso . 
data: new FormData(this),
processData: false,
contentType: false,
Tente com isso.

Comment: Bah muito obrigado, dessa forma agora funcionou certinho, enviando tanto com anexo e sem anexo, valeu mesmo, estava a 1 semana pesquisando em um monte de forum e nao conseguia resolver. grande abraço.

Comment: Se a resposta foi útil, marque como respondida para ajudar outras pessoas

Comment: Bah desculpa, unico detalhe que o campo mensagem esta indo em branco em ambos os casos: 
Formulario de Contato Preenchido no Site
Nome: William 
E-Mail: wbdemski@gmail.com 
Telefone: 48996012764 
Empresa: Tsa 
Cidade: Criciuma SC 
Assunto: Trabalhe Conosco 
Mensagem:
Sera que é por que o campo onde vai o anexo esta antes do campo da mensagem?

Comment: Colocando o campo de anexo no final do formulário o problema foi resolvido. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Que bom, disponha

Comment: Desculpe a ignorância mais sou novo no forum, como marco como respondida?

Comment: Abaixo de onde você vota a resposta

Comment: Para marcar uma resposta como aceita, clique na marca de verificação do lado esquerdo da resposta; sua cor mudará de cinza para verde.